# How to manage string resources in Android

Tags: java, android, string, resources

I have to use many url strings in Android project.

First I stored them as `class variable` but there are so many strings so I tried to store them as string resources in `strings.xml`.
However it's too hard since url includes a lot of special characters like `&, /, %` I have to convert them using `<![CDATA[]>`.

What is the most effiecient way to store those strings in Android?

Answer (score 1):

If they are URLs, there is no point in storing them in strings.xml. Strings.xml is for internationalization and localization and URLs don't need that. So store them in a constants class like you were doing before.

Comment: Is it recommended to make a class only for the use of variables  in Java?(like `.h` file in `C`)

Comment: of constants common in various parts of the program, yes, it is better to have only a single definition of that constant in some class